# zip I/O error: No such file or directory error when directory exists?

Tags: bash, git, zip, git-bash

I am not sure why I am getting this output as I believe I am hopefully doing it correctly.  I ran this script a few hours ago just testing some things and it worked just fine I had thought.  I was able to zip the target with no errors.

The current directory is the proper folder containing the target file.  The script is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

echo Zipping Backup

zip -r "backup-$(date +"%D-%H-%M-%S").zip" test
```

There is just a simple empty folder in the directory named test.  Here is the exact output running this script:

```
Zipping Backup
zip I/O error: No such file or directory
zip error: Could not create output file (backup-05/11/20-20-15-04.zip)
```

Wondering what sort of novice thing I may be overlooking here.

Comment: You probably don't want a date format that includes directory separators unless you want to put your zip file in a directory tree. And if you do, all those directories in the path need to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
backup-05/11/20-20-15-04.zip
```

The problem is obviously in slashes which are path separators. There is no directory `backup-05/11/` hence the error. Fix your format:

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"
```

without slashes.

Comment: Thank you that was it.  I remember now I did end up changing the formatting due to how it displayed %T which was also breaking the script.  I must have altered that to try to make it cleaner.  Thank you for the help!